# menu item does not click by Selenium WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Please see the below code snippet. I want to click the menu item: "Account Management", the Java function did not return.  The menu item was shown & I could manually click.

```
<body ...> <div ...> <div...>
  <ul...>
    <li class="x">
      <a class="y" key="z", href="javascript:void(0)">
        <span class="z2" lan="14377" v="Account Management">Account Management</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Code

```
public static boolean actionClickByXPath(WebDriver browser, String xpath) {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, 3);
    JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) browser);     
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath)));  

    //scrolling
    WebElement webelement = browser.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)); 
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", webelement);

    //clickable
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xpath)));

    boolean clicked = false;
    do{
        try {
            webelement.click();
        } catch (WebDriverException e) {
            Sleep(200);
            continue;
        } finally {
            clicked = true;
        }
    } while (!clicked);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is the content of `xpath`?

Comment: String acctManagementTagPath = "//*[@id=\"nav307\"]/ul/li[2]/a/span";

Comment: I just changed a bit. The function DID NOT RETURN. The xpath is real copied from Chrome. My html code was just simplified.

Comment: I sleep 500 ms before every line of the code, it worked. but I am not sure if it is stable

Answer (score 0):

Try to click by the text `Account Management`

```
.//*[contains(text(), 'Account Management')]
```

Or

```
.//*[contains(., 'Account Management')]
```

I also changed a bit the order of the code

```
JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) browser);
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", webelement);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, 3);
WebElement webelement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xpath)));
webelement.click();
```